# How to search and replace text from one file to another using Python?

Tags: python, text-files, replace

I have a file *file1.txt* :

```
I Show more flower you can see by link
All is Beautyfull.You Can View Here !
Link View :

http://lincoln.com/view/12432134/flower1.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/34645645/flower3456.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/75634534/flower56.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/86764454/flower2.jpg
```

and another one *file2.txt* :

```
http://lincoln.com/view/43645645/flower1.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/84344454/flower3456.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/43343433/flower56.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/13424324/flower2.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/343434344/flower1.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/766454544/flower3456.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/32634545/flower56.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/84353453/flower2.jpg
```

What I want is the following :

```
I Show more flower you can see by link
All is Beautyfull.You Can View Here !
Link View :

http://lincoln.com/view/43645645/flower1.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/84344454/flower3456.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/43343433/flower56.jpg    
http://lincoln.com/view/13424324/flower2.jpg

More Link VIew:

http://kashi.com/view/343434344/flower1.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/766454544/flower3456.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/32634545/flower56.jpg    
http://kashi.com/view/84353453/flower2.jpg    
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I Show more candy you can see by link
All is Beautyfull.You Can View Here !
http://photobucket.com
```

The pseudo-code being :

```
if filename exists in file1 but not in file2:
    remove filename
else if filename exists in file1 and in file2:
    the version in file2 replaces the line in file1
else if filename exists in file2 but not in file1:
    do nothing

add the links with the domaine name "http://kashi.com" from file2.txt
in a section "More link view"
add "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
```

I Tried this algorithm :

```
def file_merge(file1name,file2name):
    file1contents = list()
    file2contents = list()
    file1 = open(file1name, 'U')
    for line in file1:
        line = line.replace('\n','')
        line = line.split('/')
        file1contents.append(line)
    file1.close()
    file2 = open(file2name, 'U')
    for line in file2:
        line = line.replace('\n','')
        line = line.split('/')
        file2contents.append(line)
    file2.close()
    file3contents = file1contents
    for x in file2contents:
        for y in file1contents:
            if x[-1] == y[-1]:
                file3contents[file3contents.index(y)] = x

    file3 = open(file1name,'w')
    for line in file3contents:
        file3.write(str('/'.join(line))+'\n')
    file3.close()

file_merge('file1.txt','file2.txt')
```

Thanks!

---

simple is :
replace "filename" in file2.txt with "filename" in file1.txt

and append link http://kashi.com and 'filename' into  a content  before keyword"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

as:

```
[img]http://photobucket.com/98a267d32b056fb0a5c8c07dd4c35cc5.jpg[/img]

Fomart:IMG 
Quality:High



http://lincoln.com/view/4148476844/flower1.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148476994/flowe2.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148501374/flower3.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148476324/flower4.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148494685/flower5.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148626615/flowew6.jpg

You Can VIEW More Link !



More Link:
http://kashi.com/view/414865/flower1.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/6344353/flower2.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/234234/flower3.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/6543534/flower4.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/2342342/flower5.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/234234/flower6.jpg


++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[img]http://phtobucket.com/004_8N9FEWFZD7ECJC6.jpg[/img]
Format:Img
Quality:High


http://lincoln.com/view/4148633524/candy1.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148538064/candy2.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148537824/candy3.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148562565/candy4.jpg
http://lincoln.com/view/4148562035/candy5.jpg




You Can VIEW More Link !




More Link:
http://kashi.com/view/23423423/candy1.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/345345/candy2.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/234234/candy3.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/3434342/candy4.jpg
http://kashi.com/view/234234234/candy5.jpg
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...
...
And more content as above
```

Comment: You are only checking for 'jpg' filenames to match but if they don't you are not taking care of your 2 conditions :
"1>If filename exists in file1 but not in file2 2> If filename exists in file2 but not in file1, it is do nothing And add http://kashi.com "

Comment: @j3oy9x In this thread, you're soliloquizing without taking account of what is written to you. Your 2 preceding questions got 9 downvotes. You have a peculiar way of communicating. You should think about that. Personally, I'll never pay more attention to your questions and edits as long as they will remain the same . You should consider what I'm writing here. Have a good life.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import urlparse
import os

def file_merge(file1name,file2name):

    file1contents = list()
    file2contents = list()

    file1 = open(file1name, 'U')
    file1contents = file1.readlines()
    file1.close()

    file2 = open(file2name, 'U')
    file2contents = file2.readlines()
    file2.close()

    file3contents = []

    for link in file2contents:
        temp = urlparse.urlsplit(link)
        dirname, filename = os.path.split(temp.path)

        file3contents.append(link)

        linkin1 = False
        for l_link in file1contents[4:]:
            if l_link.endswith(filename):
                linkin1 = True

        if not linkin1:
            urllist = list(temp)
            urllist[1] = 'kashi.com'
            file3contents[-1] = urlparse.urlunsplit(urllist)


    file3 = open(file1name,'w')
    for line in file3contents:
        file3.write(line)
    file3.close()

file_merge('/tmp/file1.txt','/tmp/file2.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tested your code .But it does not achieve the desired results.All I need is:If filename exists in file1 but not in file2, it is remove If filename exists in file1 and file2, the version in file2 replaces the line in file1 If filename exists in file2 but not in file1, it is do nothing And add http://kashi.com is More Link View follow filename before keyword "++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Can you please specify the 3 cases exclusively, as per my understanding:
Case 1: Filename exists in file1 but not in file2 - remove it
Case 2: Filename exists in file1 and file2 - entry of file2 remains
Case 3: Filename not in file1 but exists in file2 - add kashi.com to domain name

Let me know which case is failing.

Answer (score 2):

try this, please:

```
with open('file2.txt','r') as f2:
    dic2 = {}
    li2 = []
    for line in f2:
        spli = line.rstrip().replace('http://','').split('/')
        dic2[(spli[0],spli[-1])] = line if line[-1]=='\n' else line+'\n'
        li2.append((spli[0],spli[-1]))

with open('file1.txt','r') as f1,open('file3.txt','w') as f3:

    itr1 = iter(f1)

    for line in itr1:
        f3.write(line)
        if line.strip()=='':
            break

    for line in itr1:
        if line.strip():
            spli = line.rstrip().replace('http://','').split('/')
            x = (spli[0],spli[-1])
            if x in li2:
                f3.write(dic2[x])
                li2.remove((spli[0],spli[-1]))
    klu = '\n' if line.rstrip()==line else ''
    # to add a blank line if the last line wasn't '\n'-ended
    f3.write(klu + '\nMore Link VIew:\n\n')

    for remain in li2:
        f3.write(dic2[remain])

    f3.write('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ')
```

Answer (score 1):

This works; however it really seems to me very strange question in the first place...sorry...

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import os.path

def read_links2(f):
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        url = urlparse(line)
        if url.scheme in ('http', 'https'):
            key = (url.netloc, os.path.split(url.path)[1])
            yield (key, url)

links2 = dict(read_links2(open('f2.txt', 'U')))

for line in open('f1.txt', 'U'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    url = urlparse(line)
    if url.scheme in ('http', 'https'):
        key = (url.netloc, os.path.split(url.path)[1])
        if key in links2:
            print links2[key].geturl()
    else:
        print line

print 'More Link VIew:'

for url in links2.values():
    if url.netloc == 'kashi.com':
        print url.geturl()


print '+++++++++++++++++++'
```