# How To Replace and Append URL in File text with Keyword By Python?

Tags: python, url, replace, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search and replace text from one file to another using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499739/how-to-search-and-replace-text-from-one-file-to-another-using-python)

I have `file1.txt` :

```
<echo http://photobucket.com/98a267d32b056fb0a5c8c07dd4c35cc5.jpg ?>


http://lincoln.com/view/filename1.jpg

http://lincoln.com/banner1/filename2.jpg

http://lincoln.com/banner1/filename3.jpg
```

And I have `file2.txt`:

```
http://lincoln.com/banner2/filename1.jpg

http://lincoln.com/banner2/filename2.jpg
```

i want :

if filename exists in file1 but not in file2:

```
      remove line have filename
```

else if filename exists in file1 and in file2:

```
      the version in file2 replaces the line in file1
```

else if filename exists in file2 but not in file1:

```
      do nothing
```

every help me code it ! Thanks!

---

i tried this code:
Can you help me edit my  code !

```
def file_merge(file1,file2):
    file1contents = list()
    file2contents = list()
    file1=open('file1.txt','r')
    for line in file1:
        line= line.replace('\n','')
        line= line.split('/')

        file1contents.append(line)
    file1.close()
    file2=open('file2.txt','r')
    for line in file2:
        line = line.replace('\n','')
        line = line.split('/')
        file2contents.append(line)
    file2.close()
    file3contents=file1contents

    for x in file2contents:
        for y in file1contents:
            if x[-1] == y[-1] and x[2]==y[2]:
                file3contents[file3contents.index(y)]=x

           here I want code :if filename exists in file1 but not in file2:
                             remove line have filename in file 1





    file3 = open('out.txt','w')
    for line in file3contents:

        file3.write(str('/'.join(line))+'\n')

    file3.close()

file_merge('file1.txt','file2.txt')
```

Comment: `remove line have filename` from where ? from both files ? only from file1 ?

Comment: remove line have filename in file1 ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works given your urls are of the type 'http' as in your example.

```
import os
base = os.path.basename

f2_lines = [line.strip() for line in open("file2.txt")]

mylines = []
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.startswith('http'):
            mylines.append(line)
            continue
        filepath = base(line) 
        for f2_line in f2_lines:
            if filepath == base(f2_line):
                mylines.append(f2_line)
                break

with open("file3.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(mylines))
```

if you do not want a third file3 created just use file1.txt and it will be overwritten.